# How to get ALL id's inside of a DIV using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I want to get every single ID of every element inside of a Div at once, and change all of their class names. Like:

```
<div id = "container">
    <div id = "alot"></div>
    <div id = "of"></div>
    <div id = "random"></div>
    <div id = "ids"></div>
</div>

<script>
    var everyId = //all of the ids in #container. but how ?
    document.getElementById( everyId ).className = "anything";
</script>
```

I've seen solutions using libraries but Is this possible with pure Javascript?

Comment: Loop through them and fetch `.id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leverage [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll) and a loop to achieve what you're looking for:

```
var everyChild = document.querySelectorAll("#container div");
for (var i = 0; i<everyChild.length; i++) {
    everyChild[i].classList.add("anything");
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vzn7bwww/)

Comment: yes but using your JSFiddle why Can't I remove a class name? http://jsfiddle.net/vzn7bwww/1/

Comment: You're making a syntaxical error in your approach, calling `.replace()` **does not** *set* the value: you need to **set** the variable separately. [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vzn7bwww/2/). You can also use [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList)'s `remove()` method.

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this:

```
var ids = [];
var children = document.getElementById("container").children; //get container element children.
for (var i = 0, len = children.length ; i < len; i++) {
    children[i].className = 'new-class'; //change child class name.
    ids.push(children[i].id); //get child id.
}

console.log(ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use querySelectorAll for the Child elements within the specified parent:

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll('#container > div'); // get all children within container
console.log(a);
for (var i = 0; i<a.length; i++){ // loop over the elements
    console.log(a[i].id);  //  get the ids
    a[i].className = 'newClass';  // change the class names
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) to provide a selector to fetch the elements you are interested in.

```
var c = document.querySelectorAll("#container > div");
console.log(c);  // array of all children div below #container
```