# How to get all IDs from div element?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get all IDs within both div elements but I don't know why the following code is not working (taken example from here [How to get ALL id's inside of a DIV using pure javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27629122/how-to-get-all-ids-inside-of-a-div-using-pure-javascript)). Please advice.

These are my attempts so far

**Attempt #1**

```js
var everyChild = document.querySelectorAll('#col-x-z.ab.def');
for (var i = 0; i < everyChild.length; i++) {
  console.log(everyChild[i]);
}
```

**Attempt #2**

```js
var c = document.querySelectorAll('##col-x-z.ab.def > div');
console.log(c);
```

Here is my source code:

```css
.col-x-z.ab.def {
  border: 4px outset red;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}
.portlet.box.blue {
  border: 2px outset blue;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-x-z ab def" id="sortable_portlets">
  <div class="col-x-z ab def" id="col_1" col="1">
    <div id="353" class="portlet box blue">x</div>
    <div id="355" class="portlet box blue">x</div>
    <div id="358" class="portlet box blue">x</div>
    <div id="353" class="portlet box blue">x</div>
    <div id="360" class="portlet box blue">x</div>
    <div id="363" class="portlet box blue">x</div>
    <div id="365" class="portlet box blue">x</div>
    <div id="367" class="portlet box blue">x</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-x-z ab def" id="col_2" col="2">
    <div id="473" class="portlet box blue">y</div>
    <div id="475" class="portlet box blue">y</div>
    <div id="478" class="portlet box blue">y</div>
    <div id="473" class="portlet box blue">y</div>
    <div id="480" class="portlet box blue">y</div>
    <div id="483" class="portlet box blue">y</div>
    <div id="485" class="portlet box blue">y</div>
    <div id="487" class="portlet box blue">y</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're trying to select an `id` that doesn't exist. Your `class` attribute is what you're trying to select. `#col-x-z.ab.def` should be `.col-x-z.ab.def`. `#` is for the id attribute, `.` is for the class attribute.

Comment: Thank you. I've changed as you suggested doing like this `var everyChild = document.querySelectorAll(".col-x-z.ab.def");
for (var i = 0; i<everyChild.length; i++) {
 console.log(everyChild[i]);
}` Now, I have issue in how to print all IDs. May you help me with that?

Comment: I think the answer should be what you're looking for. If not, we'll need some clarification on what you're trying to get.

Comment: @Suspeg please take a look both of the solutions in my answer. The first is grouped by the parent ID in an object, the second is a simple array of all the desired IDs together

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName(" portlet box blue"),
    ids = [], i = 0;

    while( coll[ i ] ) { ids.push( coll[ i++ ].id ) };
    console.log( ids );
```

```html
<div class="col-x-z ab def" id="sortable_portlets">
        <div class="col-x-z ab def" id="col_1" col="1">
            <div id="353" class=" portlet box blue">x</div>
            <div id="355" class=" portlet box blue">x</div>
            <div id="358" class=" portlet box blue">x</div>
            <div id="353" class=" portlet box blue">x</div>
            <div id="360" class=" portlet box blue">x</div>
            <div id="363" class=" portlet box blue">x</div>
            <div id="365" class=" portlet box blue">x</div>
            <div id="367" class=" portlet box blue">x</div>
        </div>
</div>      
    <div class="col-x-z ab def" id="col_2" col="2">
            <div id="473" class=" portlet box blue">y</div>
            <div id="475" class=" portlet box blue">y</div>
            <div id="478" class=" portlet box blue">y</div>
            <div id="473" class=" portlet box blue">y</div>
            <div id="480" class=" portlet box blue">y</div>
            <div id="483" class=" portlet box blue">y</div>
            <div id="485" class=" portlet box blue">y</div>
            <div id="487" class=" portlet box blue">y</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works exactly how I need. And avoids to print extra elements that doesn't have `id`.

Comment: @Suspeg, thanks, if you any explanations, just ask in the comments below, I'll incorporate them in the original answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to get all IDs grouped by parent ID, this will do that:

```js
var c = Object.fromEntries(Array.from(document.querySelector('#sortable_portlets').children).map(e => [e.id, Array.from(e.children).map(f => f.id).filter(f => f)]));
console.log(c);
```

```css
.col-x-z.ab.def { border: 4px outset red; background-color: lightblue; text-align: center; } portlet.box.blue { border: 2px outset blue; background-color: lightblue; text-align: center; }
```

```html
<div class="col-x-z ab def" id="sortable_portlets"><div class="col-x-z ab def" id="col_1" col="1"><div id="353" class=" portlet box blue">x</div><div id="355" class=" portlet box blue">x</div><div id="358" class=" portlet box blue">x</div><div id="353" class=" portlet box blue">x</div><div id="360" class=" portlet box blue">x</div><div id="363" class=" portlet box blue">x</div><div id="365" class=" portlet box blue">x</div><div id="367" class=" portlet box blue">x</div></div><div class="col-x-z ab def" id="col_2" col="2"><div id="473" class=" portlet box blue">y</div><div id="475" class=" portlet box blue">y</div><div id="478" class=" portlet box blue">y</div><div id="473" class=" portlet box blue">y</div><div id="480" class=" portlet box blue">y</div><div id="483" class=" portlet box blue">y</div><div id="485" class=" portlet box blue">y</div><div id="487" class=" portlet box blue">y</div></div></div>
```

If you just want a simple array of all IDs, use this:

```js
var c = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#sortable_portlets > .col-x-z.ab.def > div')).map(e => e.id).filter(e => e);
console.log(c);
```

```css
.col-x-z.ab.def { border: 4px outset red; background-color: lightblue; text-align: center; } portlet.box.blue { border: 2px outset blue; background-color: lightblue; text-align: center; }
```

```html
<div class="col-x-z ab def" id="sortable_portlets"><div class="col-x-z ab def" id="col_1" col="1"><div id="353" class=" portlet box blue">x</div><div id="355" class=" portlet box blue">x</div><div id="358" class=" portlet box blue">x</div><div id="353" class=" portlet box blue">x</div><div id="360" class=" portlet box blue">x</div><div id="363" class=" portlet box blue">x</div><div id="365" class=" portlet box blue">x</div><div id="367" class=" portlet box blue">x</div></div><div class="col-x-z ab def" id="col_2" col="2"><div id="473" class=" portlet box blue">y</div><div id="475" class=" portlet box blue">y</div><div id="478" class=" portlet box blue">y</div><div id="473" class=" portlet box blue">y</div><div id="480" class=" portlet box blue">y</div><div id="483" class=" portlet box blue">y</div><div id="485" class=" portlet box blue">y</div><div id="487" class=" portlet box blue">y</div></div></div>
```

Comment: Excellent. It works perfect. Only one thing. I tested in actual file and I see that `div` for `col_1` and `div` for `col_2` have an extra `div` within them that doesn't have id. Like this `<div class=" wqp"></div>` In this case is printing 18 ID elements and 2 with `""` empty values. How to print only the 16 IDs, those IDs from DIV elements that actually have IDs? Thanks again

Comment: @Suspeg No worries. I've just added a single check `.filter(f => f)` to both implementations which filters out any falsy values which will account for any `undefined` values and empty strings (`""`). Please test again and let me know if this works. If my solution works for you, please consider selecting my solution as the chosen answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: @Suspeg may I ask what swayed you away from my solution(s), so I can better assist in the future? They are more simply written. Were they harder to understand?